# Cant connect to any of the Input and Output Stream

Tags: java, android

```
 String pass_url = "http://192.168.1.8/eplusv2/android/demo.php";
   try {
     URL url=new URL(pass_url);
       HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       con.setRequestMethod("POST");
       InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
       String result="";
       String line = "";
       while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
           result += line;
       }
       inputStream.close();
       bufferedReader.close();
       con.disconnect();


   }catch (Exception e){

   }
```

I cant connect to the any of the input or output stream usng the above code.And while debugging this code,in the console i getting the message like

```
D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40002181, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
```

Comment: could your print the whole exception stack trace?

Comment: D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x5F
W/asset: AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.focture.foctureeplusv2 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x14

Comment: You are not posting anything.  But you did tell that you were gonna do. You should first write something. After that do read response.

Comment: Please do not post stacktraces as comments. Just add them to your post instead.

Comment: Error:-                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
                      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
                      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76

Comment: You should not post lines of the console but of the logcat. `catch (Exception e){

   }`. Your catch block is empty. Not only you should put e.printStackTrace(); in it but also log e.getMessage(). And try to inform the user of your app that something goes wrong.

Comment: Do not use Strictmode. Remove all that code and use a normal AsyncTask or thread to do network operations. You again posted logcat as comment. Dont do that! Remove those comment!